# Action Script 3. How to get time from game and insert to database?

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3, flash, timer

I'm creating flash game. Here is timer, which counts how long player playing. When "Game is over" counter stops. And I need to write this time to database. My counter format is MM:SS, so I don't know how to do It.

Here is my code to send data from game to php:

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("band.php");

// Set the method to POST
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// Define the variables to post    
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.time = timer.currentCount;
urlVars.userName = "myUserName";

// Add the variables to the URLRequest
urlReq.data = urlVars;  

// Add the URLRequest data to a new Loader
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq);

// Set a listener function to run when completed
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoginComplete);

// Set the loader format to variables and post to the PHP
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(urlReq);
```

So i send my `time` variable to php.

Here is php code to get time:

```
<?php 
$time = $_POST['time'];
$username = $_POST['userName'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO eurokos (time, userName)
    VALUES ('$time', '$username')"); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO eurokos VALUES" . "('$time', '$username')";
    echo "success=true";

?>
```

So username sucessfully insterting to database, that means everything is finy with sending variables to php, but time always "0" value, so that means something wrong with timer.

My timer looks like:

```
function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {

  var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
  var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds
  var leadingZeroM:String = "";

  var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
  var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 

  if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
    leadingZeroMS = "0";
  }

  var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

  if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroS = "0";
  }

  var minutes = Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000) ) );
    if (minutes < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
    leadingZeroM = "0";
  }
  //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
  return leadingZeroM + minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds ;     
}
```

I don't know whats wrong, why time not inserting to database. Could you help me? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 
        $time = $_POST['time'];
    $username = $_POST['userName'];
    session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['vardas']; 
    $times = gmdate('H:m:s', $time);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","padekime_db","pass","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $query = "INSERT INTO eurokos VALUES" . "('$times', '$username')";
    echo "success=true";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into eurokos (time, userName) VALUE (?,?) ")) {

   $stmt->bind_param("i", $time);
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
   $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
    function startMemoryGame():void
    {
        addChild(CardContainer);

            timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);
            txtTime = new TextField();



        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Verdana";
        format.color = "#E50041";
        format.size = 22;
        txtTime.border = true;
        txtTime.borderColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        //format.bold = true;  
        //txtTime.x = 250;
        txtTime.width/2;



        var stageCenter_x:Number = stage.stageWidth/2;
        var stageCenter_y:Number = stage.stageHeight/2;

        var textCenter_x:Number = txtTime.width/2;
        var textCenter_y:Number = txtTime.height/2;

        txtTime.x = stageCenter_x - textCenter_x;
        txtTime.y = 55;

        txtTime.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
       txtTime.defaultTextFormat = format;
       message_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
       message_txt.defaultTextFormat = format;

                        txtTime.text = setNull(0);
            addChild(txtTime);
            tmpTime = getTimer();
            timer.start();
            }

private function tick(e:Event):void {
       txtTime.text = showTimePassed(tmpTime);                  


    }
    function setNull(startTime:int):String {
     return "00:00";
    }
    function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {

      var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
      var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds
      var leadingZeroM:String = "";

      var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
      var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 

      if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
        leadingZeroMS = "0";
      }

      var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

      if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroS = "0";
      }

      var minutes = Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000) ) );
        if (minutes < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroM = "0";
      }
      //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
      return leadingZeroM + minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds ;



    }

    function getTimePassed(startTime:int):Number {
     return  (getTimer() - startTime) /1000;
    }
```

Here send variable to php:

```
  var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("band.php");

    // Set the method to POST
    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    // Define the variables to post    
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    urlVars.userName = 'myUsername';

    urlVars.time = getTimePassed(startTime); // HERE I GET ERROR
    // Add the variables to the URLRequest
    urlReq.data = urlVars;  

    // Add the URLRequest data to a new Loader
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq);

    // Set a listener function to run when completed
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoginComplete);

    // Set the loader format to variables and post to the PHP
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.load(urlReq);
}
```

Comment: 1/ What is the data type of the field time in mysql ? 2/ Not your primary problem but you should use prepared statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Time field type INT.

Answer (score 0):

The value of time in mysql is always 0 because MySql receive the time as string "MM:SS" and the data type of the field time is INT.

You have 2 solutions : converts MM:SS to number of seconds on the PHP side before the insert query or send the total of seconds from the flash side (better from my pov).

**Update :** get the elapsed time directly from timer instance

[...]

```
urlVars.time = timer.currentCount; // time elapsed in seconds
```

On the PHP side, use prepared statements :

**Update :** full script to save time / username in DB
[...]

```
$time = $_POST['time'];
$username = $_POST['userName'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","padekime_db","pass","my_db");

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into eurokos (time, userName) VALUES (?,?) ")) {

   $stmt->bind_param('is',$time,$username);

   $stmt->execute();

   if ($stmt->error != '') {
       echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
   } else {
       echo 'success';
   }
   $stmt->close();
} else {
   echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
}
```

If you `trace` the value of `loader.data` in the `onLoginComplete` handler, you should see "success" or "error:the error description"

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: I updated my question how my code looks like now. But doesn't work.

Comment: When I use that code you gave in flash I got error: `1120: Access of undefined property startTime.`

Comment: Well, you have to adapt a bit to your context... I dont know where you calculate time in your code. The idea is that you get the time you want to save (int format) when you define the time property in your URLVariables object.

Comment: I updated my question how my code looks like now, why I get this error I don't understand.

Comment: I updated the answer, you dont need the getTimePassed function, just get the elapsed time directly from the timer instance.

Comment: I used this before `urlVars.time = timer.currentCount;` but this send time in MM:SS and I can't insert It to database.

Comment: timer.currentCount is a integer, it indicates the number of tick in the timer object since it started. Problem is that you have several issues on your PHP script, check the PHP on my answer.

Comment: I got error when I use this code.
`Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/padekime/domains/padekime.eu/public_html/band.php on line 13`

`Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/padekime/domains/padekime.eu/public_html/band.php on line 14`
error:No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Comment: Error on these lines:
`$stmt->bind_param("i", $time); $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);`

Comment: my bad, should be : $stmt->bind_param('is',$time,$username); I update the answer.

Comment: Here is something wrong with my as file. If I use this for test: `function testButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
var test = timer.currentCount;
trace(test);
}` It always return 0

Comment: I found mistake, I need to use `urlVars.time = showTimePassed(tmpTime);` This returns time MM:SS, but to database write 0 value, the same, my database table where I want to instert is INT, maybe I need to change It to other format or what?

Comment: This is wrong way, this doesn't stop when game over. If I use timer.stop(); timer stops counting, but `showTimePassed(tmpTime);` not stops. So I don't know which one variable now show current time, how long played till timer stops. because `timer.currentCount;` return 0...